# How to remove SubView with slide in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiview

I tried to add SubView with animation following codes.It's okay.

```
[self.view addSubview:pickerView];
    pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                     animations:^{
                         pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 152, 320, 260);
                     }];
```

And i also want to remove the subView with slide animation like above animation.

How can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could use this animateWithDuration completion block to remove the view

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                 animations:^{
                     pickerView.frame = //move it out of screen
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [pickerView removeFromSuperView];
                 }];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
         pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);   

        } completion:^(BOOL finished){
            [pickerView removeFromSuperView];          
        }];
```